# MySQL LOAD DATA IN FILE Not Inserting all the values

Tags: mysql, database, mariadb, load-data-infile

I have a text file in the following format, which contains about a million coupon codes.

```
93C9LF,PDF934,24YWJ4
93C9LF,PDF934,24YWJ4
93C9LF,PDF934,24YWJ4
```

Below is my query

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE /var/www/coupons.txt
INTO TABLE coupons
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '' ENCLOSED BY '' ESCAPED BY ''
LINES STARTING BY '' TERMINATED BY ','
(coupon);
```

When I execute this query only some are inserted into the database. I would like to know what I am doing wrong or what could be done to improve this query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi Rezaq you can use this:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/var/www/coupons.txt' 
INTO TABLE coupons 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'
ENCLOSED BY ',' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
(coupon);
```

Comment: +TERMINATED BY '\t'+ ... shouldn't that be +TERMINATED BY ','+ here?

I clearly see a comma as field delimiter in the example above, not a tabulator sign (or other whitespace)

Comment: This works totally fine. @BviLLe_Kid. I am loading this into a single column not multiple column.

Comment: @Rezaq I wasn't the one who answered the question